# sort ordered items by product name in magento admin

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, sales-order

I want to sort items ordered by product name in magento backend. I followed this link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17572936/magento-change-sort-order-of-ordered-items, but what this is doing is removing products with the same name(like in configurable different simple products). Please help/

Answer (score 2):

The order items are displayed in the backend using the tempalte `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items.phtml`.

You should not edit the core file, so you should create your own admin theme and copy the file in that theme, keeping the relative path.  Let's call that theme `custom`.
So create the folder `app/design/adminhtml/default/custom/template/sales/order/view`.
Copy the file `items.phtml` mentioned above to this folder.
Now add this in the config.xml from one of your extensions inside the `<config>` tag.

```
<stores>
    <admin>
        <design>
            <theme>
                <default>custom</default>
            </theme>
        </design>
    </admin>
</stores>
```

More details about setting a custom admin theme can be found [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/admin/using_custom_admin_theme_templates).

Now in the template you need to change the sort of the items.

So after this line `<?php $_items = $this->getItemsCollection() ?>` add the following code.

```
<?php 
$sorted = array();
foreach ($_items as $_item) {
    if ($_item->getParentItem()) { //skip dummy products
      continue; 
    }
    $itemName = $item->getName();
    if (!isset($sorted[$itemName])) {
        $sorted[$itemName] = array();
    }
    $sorted[$itemName][] = $item;  //use an array for each name, in case there are items with the same name.
}
//sort the items by name
ksort($sorted);
//now you have in $sorted a 2-dimensional array. Let's make it 1 dimension.

$allItems = array();
foreach ($sorted as $name => $items) {
    $allItems = array_merge($allItems, $items);
}
?>
```

Now you have in `$allItems` the items sorted by name.
Replace the line `<?php $i=0;foreach ($_items as $_item):?>` with

```
<?php $i=0;foreach ($allItems as $_item):?>
```

and you are done.